# kubuntu find not working properly in home directory

Tags: kubuntu, find, dolphin, baloo

Opening a terminal in my home directory, the following commands yield no results:

```
~$ find . -name 'mysql'
~$ find ./ -name 'mysql'
~$ find /home/username/ -name 'mysql'
```

but if I chdir to my local subdirectory 'bin' it works

```
~/bin$ find -name 'mysql'
./manuals/mysql
```

or issue the command this way

```
find /home/username/bin/ -name 'mysql'
/home/username/bin/manuals/mysql
```

Could this behaviour be one of the reasons the find function in dolphin is not working (in my home directory, anyway)?  Because dolphin find seems to work in in other directories

--oh yes: Desktop Search is enabled.

-tia

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to reflect some bias here, a bias which appears to be unpopular.  you see, I've been using Kubuntu and Ubuntu for various parts of a decade.  I cut my teeth on Kubuntu for over a year, and for about the past 9 years, I've been using Ubuntu instead.  I simply found too many unnecessary and nonsensical obstacles in Kubuntu that Ubuntu simply didn't have.

I don't claim to understand why Kubuntu seems determined to make people feel stupid, but I run into this a lot.

If you have a spare pc, or even a spare hard drive you can use for test purposes, please repeat your tests on Ubuntu and write back to tell us if you have the same problems in Ubuntu.  I doubt you will, but I'd like confirmation.